# Redis cluster integration with spring boot - err This instance has cluster support disabled

Tags: java, redis, spring-data-redis, jedis, amazon-elasticache

I have application written in spring boot connected with redis in standalone mode. Now I moved from standalone to clustered mode but I am facing below issue while changing client level code.

`nested exception is redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisDataException: ERR This instance has cluster support disabled`

I had spent lot of time & tried lot of solutions but it didn’t worked. Maybe I am missing something. Any clue why my client is not recognising cluster mode.

1. Added following configs in redis.conf file & run the redis instance in cluster mode

port 6379.
cluster-enabled yes.
cluster-config-file nodes.conf.
cluster-node-timeout 15000.
appendonly yes.

2. Redis config : 127.0.0.1:6379

Code

```
public RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
        log.debug("Redis host {} and port {}", redisHost, redisPort);
        JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory;
        if (clusterEnabled) {
            String[] redisNodes = redisClusterNodes.split(",");
            List<String> redisNodesList = Arrays.asList(redisNodes);
            RedisClusterConfiguration redisClusterConfiguration = new RedisClusterConfiguration(redisNodesList);
            jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(redisClusterConfiguration);
        } else {
            final RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisStandaloneConfiguration =
                    new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, Integer.parseInt(redisPort));
            redisStandaloneConfiguration.setPassword(redisPassword);
            redisStandaloneConfiguration.setDatabase(Integer.parseInt(redisDbIndex));
            jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(redisStandaloneConfiguration);
        }
        return jedisConnectionFactory;
    }
```

version

springBootVersion = '2.0.5.RELEASE'
name: 'spring-data-redis', version: '2.1.3.RELEASE'
name: 'jedis', version: '2.9.0'

Can anyone help what I am doing wrong or missing , I have tried almost all possible solution for the above issue .

Comment: did you get the solution for this